# How to type hint a Callable of a function with default arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to Type Hint the function `bar`, but I got the `Too few arguments` error when I run mypy.

```
from typing import Callable, Optional

def foo(arg: int = 123) -> float:
    return arg+0.1

def bar(foo: Callable[[int], float], arg: Optional[int] = None) -> float:
    if arg:
        return foo(arg)
    return foo()

print(bar(foo))
print(bar(foo, 90))
```

I have also tried:

- `Callable[[], float]` (got `Too many arguments` error)
- `Callable[[Optional[int]], float]` (got another error)

So, how should I do the Type Hinting of the `bar` function?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Define this:

```
class Foo(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int = ..., /) -> float:
        ...
```

then type hint `foo` as `Foo` instead of `Callable[[int], float]`. [Callback protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) allow you to:

> define flexible callback types that are hard (or even impossible) to express using the `Callable[...]` syntax

and optional arguments are one of those impossible things to express with a normal `Callable`. The `/` at the end of `__call__`'s signature makes `x` a [positional-only parameter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/#function-examples), which allows any passed function to `bar` to have a parameter name that is not `x` (your specific example of `foo` calls it `arg` instead). If you removed `/`, then not only would the types have to line up as expected, but the names would have to line up too because you would be implying that `Foo` could be called with a keyword argument. Because `bar` doesn't call `foo` with keyword arguments, opting into that behavior by omitting the `/` imposes inflexibility on the user of `bar` (and would make your current example still fail because `"arg" != "x"`).

Comment: How do you know that > "optional arguments are one of those impossible things to express with a normal Callable"?

Comment: @DonLarry Arguments with type `Optional` (`Callable[[Optional[int]], bool`) are possible to express, but you need to pass `None`. Optional arguments (so arguments with defaults) where you don't have to pass anything are not supported because it would require being able to specify `=` for the generic arguments of a `Callable` (something like `Callable[[int = 123], bool]`, which is an unsupported syntax.

Comment: Technically it wouldn't have to be `=`, could be some other syntax, but none have been agreed upon (https://github.com/python/typing/issues/264) outside of `Protocol`s.

Comment: bro, it is way different arguments with default and Optional arguments, look at this https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional "Note that this is not the same concept as an optional argument, which is one that has a default."

Comment: @DonLarry yes, that's why I made the distinction.